# Laravel - Page Not Found after changing project name

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, caching, configuration

I have changed my Laravel project name using: `php artisan app:name new_name`

My project display an error with:

```
Class 'app\Providers\EloquentEventServiceProvider' not found
```

I've made a little research and found an answered question on StackOverflow which advised me to delete /bootstrap/cache/config.php file.

I deleted it and regenerated via `php artisan config:cache`

Now my project is showing

Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

My routes/web.php look like:

```
/** Auth Routes*/
Auth::routes();

/** Homepage Route*/
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('layout');
});
```

My .htaccess file look like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Please help me!

Comment: `composer du` should work. If you were to use `php artisan app:name NewName` you shouldn't have to use `composer du` and it'll work just fine as well.

Comment: still getting `Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.`

Comment: And you're sure that "layout" is the name of a view? It's not "layouts.layout" or anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try next command:

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Comment: Okey, try next: 1)php artisan route:clear ;
2)composer dump-autoload . It fix your problem?

Comment: still getting 
`Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
php artisan config:clear
```

and change `Class 'app\Providers\EloquentEventServiceProvider'
to
Class 'App\Providers\EloquentEventServiceProvider'`
and see if it works

Comment: I got rid of that error when I deleted `/bootstrap/cache/config.php`
Now I am getting:
`Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.`

Comment: im guessing you are developing locally.if so after changing your app name make sure to also change the name of the folder on the local server.lets say you are using xampp make sure c://xampp/htdocs/yourAppName  is the same as the name you have on your config/app.php file.or just double check the name of the page is the same as the page name you are returning from your controller.Also double check that the url on your page matches the url on your web.php file.Just a couple of suggestions